# Which base64 standard should be used with URNs for forge apis?

Tags: base64, autodesk-forge, urn

In the [tutorial / docs of the model derivative API](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/prep-file4viewer/task2-upload_source_file_to_oss/) it is mentioned URNs should be urlsafe base64 encoded according to [RCF 6920](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6920) but the spec is not mentioned in the [full list of base64 variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table) also mentioned in the tutorial. Does the tutorial maybe refer to RCF 4648 or which standard should be used?

Sincerly,
Dominik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's an interesting question. I've been using all sorts of ways to encode/decode base64 when working with the Forge Model Derivative service, for example:

- with [base64 command](https://linux.die.net/man/1/base64) on *nix systems
- with [btoa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa) JavaScript function in browsers
- with [toString('base64')](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings) in Node.js
- with https://www.base64encode.org

If the documentation for these methods mentions anything, it's the [RFC 4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648#section-5), so I'd say that's the one, plus the URL safe encoding, meaning:

> the "+" and "/" characters are respectively replaced by "-" and "_", and the padding "=" signs are omitted